# VBA excel 2007 Transfer a Cell's value with a condition

Tags: excel, vba, transfer

in worksheet 'hitterscalc' cell d2, i want to paste the value of worksheet 'batters' cell ks2 if the value in 'hitterscalc' cell ab2 = 1

i think want to do this for all of the rows that have data in the worksheet 'hitterscalc'

i have come up with

```
With Worksheets("Hitterscalc")
    With .Range("d2:d" & .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=IF($AB2=1,Batters!KS2,""))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

but is returning application defined or object defined error.

can someone point me in the correct direction to fixing this issue?

edit:

so when i do

```
With Worksheets("Hitterscalc")
        With .Range("d2:d" & .Range("ab" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .Formula = "=Batters!KS2"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
```

the expression works properly. how can i get it so that it checks the cell value of worksheet hitterscalc column ab first?

edit 2

```
With Worksheets("Hitterscalc")
        With .Range("d2:d" & .Range("ab" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .Formula = "=IF(AND(A2<>"""",AB2=1),Batters!KS2,"""")"
            '.Formula = "=Batters!KS2"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
```

works. i am confused as to why this one works but not the first one.

Comment: I'd use `for each cell` construction.

Comment: im sorry i am novice enough that while i understand the idea behind what you are suggesting, implementing it is out of my grasp. i am trying to adapt pre-existing code in another one of my functions. do you happen to know why it would not be working?

Comment: I think I got the clue - see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion is because of quotes - try to use this code:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("d2:d" & .Range("ab" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            r = "=IF($AB2=1,Batters!KS2," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
            .Formula = r
            .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Formula string is generated using `Chr(34)` for double quotes used in `IF`.